# ALSA on RPi3 inside Docker with Chromium looses audio randomly

Tags: ubuntu, docker, chromium, alsa, alpine-linux

## What is the setup

I'm running Chromium 66.0.3359.181 inside Docker container running Ubuntu 16.04.4 on top of Alpine 3.7, all this Raspberry Pi 3.

## What I'm trying to achieve

I want to run an HTML5 app with sound on top of the Chromium

## What is wrong

Everythin works perfectly on certain type of RPi3 but when we purchased some new RPi3s suddenly the sound stopped working, we're not sure the sound is diverted to a different ALSA device or not playing at all.

The weird thing is that it only happens with our app on this specific type of RPi3, when launching YouTube instead everything works fine, I've also played the `.wav` files successfully with `aplay`.

I've configured `amixer cset numid=3 1`, I've configured everything in `config.txt`, I've added `export ALSA_CARD=ALSA && export ALSA_PCM_CARD=0` before the command running `chromium-browser` and also added this argument: `--alsa-output-device=plughw:CARD=ALSA,DEV=0` to chromium.

Nothing works persistently, if I'm restarting the whole machine then it doesn't work, after restarting the Docker container individually sometimes it works and sometimes don't.

I've monitored `/proc/asound/ALSA/pcm0p/sub0/hw_params` to see whether I'm experiencing anything weird but surprisingly when no sound is heard then the content keeps showing `closed` (`watch -n 0.5 cat …`).

I'm going completely crazy, I'm not sure what should I do next and what else I can try.

Comment: Replaced Ubuntu 16.04 with 18.04, same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was running `amixer cset numid=3 1` as the `chromium` user (created in order to avoid the sandbox in chromium), the only thing I should have changed is running the same command as root instead of this user.

Kind regards,
Yaron.